# WebdriverIO E2E tests - Mock a function called inside a React Component

Tags: reactjs, webdriver-io

Is there a way to mock a function called inside a React functional component using WebdriverIO?

I need to run E2E tests and validate the UI based on logic triggered inside the component, and I couldn't find a way to do it using WebdriverIO.

For example, my intention is to mock the result of `checkIfUserHasPermissions`, run the E2E test, and validate that the browser shows either "Welcome" or "Not allowed".

Jest provides a tool [to mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions), and I was wondering if WebdriverIO has something similar. On their docs, an option [to mock a React prop](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/react$.html) is available, but nothing related to this particular use case:

```
import { checkIfUserHasPermissions } from '/utils';

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {  
        checkIfUserHasPermissions() ? 
          <h1>Welcome</h1> : 
          <h1>Not allowed</h1>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: What does `checkIfUserHasPermissions` do? Your E2E tests shouldn't be interfering with the source code at all.

Comment: How would you test that the browser shows "Welcome" and also "Not allowed"? That's my point. ``checkIfUserHasPermissions`` is just an example.

Comment: From what you've posted, I don't know. In the general case I'd expect that if I visited without logging in, or logged in as a user without access to this specific page, I'd see "Not allowed" and if I then logged in as a user _with_ access I'd see "Welcome" instead. So part of the E2E test setup would be creating users with appropriate access (and, if needed, other users without) that the tests could then use.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution for an App with a simple user flow, but in my case, I need to test complex components inside a large project, and finding a way to mock atomic functions inside a specific component (something [Jest provides](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions)) would make it much easier...
Thanks for your input though, I added more details to my question.

Comment: You can test those things at other levels, E2E tests should exercise your whole system *as a real user would*. Otherwise there's little value to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible but not recommended.

There are 2 options to do that:

- change the function by executing some js with `browser.execute`. Ask your developers to help to access the function externally.
- use `browser.mock` to change the text content of the function before it's loaded. See https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/mock.html